# Fetch records using Group By from appengine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying something like this:

```
result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM myDataMode COUNT(Employee) GROUP BY(Department) WHERE Salary > :1"10000)
```

And I am getting error :

```
BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol count
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: That statement is not legal SQL *or* GQL.  As will states, GQL is not the same as SQL.  But your statement won't work in a regular SQL database either, because you can't select * and use a group by.  You need to specify the columns you want to select.

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve with this query?  Maybe we can help you write one that will work.

Comment: Thanks Peter
I know that GQL is different from SQL.
My problem is very simle
I hava a model Employee than contains Columns (Emp_id,Name,Department_id)
Now i want to count Employees working in each department.

Answer (score 5):

GQL isn't SQL.  It doesn't have `COUNT()` or `GROUP BY()`.  See the [GQL reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since GQL does not have `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` function.
so I designed a solution for it:

```
result = db.GqlQuery( SELECT * form Employee)
```

Make an Array which will have unique Departments from the result :

```
if result.Department not in array:
    array.append(result.Department)
for department in array:
    query = db.GqlQuery(SELECT * form Employee WHERE Department = :1,department)
    print "In" + department + query.count() +"Employees are working"
```