# Is it possible to access index directly?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

Say that I have a model like this:

```
User(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  interests = db.StringListProperty()
```

The document, ["How Entities and Indexes are Stored - Google App Engine — Google Developers"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown#anc-indextables), describes how they stored index.

And I'd like to get all unique `interests` among the users without fetching all users.

EDIT: I mean that getting unique set of `interests`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gql query allows you to add a [property list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference), so you can use:

```
"SELECT interest FROM User"
```

Comment: Sorry I mean that I'd like to have unique set of `interests`, but for slightly small number of data, I can use `set()` python function with results of the query. Anyway thanks.

Comment: If you keep it in one table you need to use `set()` since [Gql doesn't have `GROUP BY`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2653857/1240268)... If `set` isn't good enough perhaps a separate interests table would be a solution?

Comment: Psst!  The App Engine Datastore team is listening!  SELECT DISTINCT <properties> will be added to GQL in a future release (not 1.7.3).

Comment: haygen, yes, for my case I decided to have a master `interests` property in another table and synchronize them so that I can get all `interests` instantly.

Comment: Thank Guido for your information, I'm looking forward to `DISTINCT` ;-)

Comment: GAE 1.7.4 support DISTINCT! http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes